# Creating a custom field widget on Odoo ERP system

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I have started developing on Odoo 13 just one week ago. and I am working on development of a module that is supposed to inherit timesheet_grid app and make some fundamental changes. now what I want to do is to develop a custom widget for list/tree view that takes a date, and display the elapsed time since the given date. for example if the given time is equal 18:20, and It's 19:30 It should display 01:10.

Actually I have tried to look for different solutions to make this work like QWeb, but apparently QWeb is not supported on on tree view. and I could not find any good documentation explaining how to make custom widgets, even the official documentation doesn't explain was not that deep.

That's why I am here hopping someone can provide me with a good example or documentation on how to make custom widgets for fields.

Thank you in advance and evjoy your evening!

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/web.html#widgets-basics Here's the documentation for widgets. Feel free to update your question with things you're actually struggling with. The documentation is pretty on point with what you need to know but Odoo Widgets are complicated at the moment and trying to build one is always going to be difficult unless odoo changes the architecture.

Comment: I think you need a compute field? if not show a screen shot of what you want exactly.

Comment: @CharifDZ the computing has to be client sided. the client has to take datetime as input and display the elapsed time. If I Odoo field computing, the client will just flood the server.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Yeah, Odoo's frontend architecture is kind of complex as it super abstracted! Although I was looking to create a widget(the attribute) for tree view field, not a widget. Altho Ive managed to get this working yesterday morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working, [this documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/web.html#the-form-view-fields) can give an insight about how to create custom widget, although Its not the best documentation